# How can I activate nested class based on parent class?

Tags: html, sass, nested, parent-child

I have 2 classes one is `.bot` class and 2nd is `.tools` class. On click of filter-button class I am trying to activate (display) tools class which has dropdown button. For some reason this is not working for me.

Here is my scss code

```
.bot {
    &:active {
      .tools {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my html code

```
<button class="bot" (click)="toggleFilters()">Filter <fa-icon [icon]="filter">
 </fa-icon>
</button>
<div class="demos">
  <div class="tools"
       *ngIf="Data.length > 1">        
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead

```
.filter-button {
  &:active {
    + .demos {
      .tools {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

note the `+` selector

Comment: Its partially working, I have to long press on ```Filter``` button to get the dropdowns on the page, any thoughts how this can be fixed?

Comment: If you want to use :active selector then you will need to hold down the button. If you want to click the button and trigger it then javascript is needed. However there's some pure css trick that use checkboxes, also can achieve this without javascript

Comment: This is angular application, I plan to achieve this functionality using scss. How is it possible? :active selector is not mandatory, is there anything else I can use in place of this selector?